# C++ 98 : Initializing std::tr1::unordered_map

Tags: unordered-map, c++98, tr1

How to initialize the unordered_map in C++98. I am trying below:

```
1. const std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, int> mymap = {{key1,1}};
2. const std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, int> mymap = {std::make_pair(key1,1)};
```

Compiler throws error:

```
C++98 ‘mymap’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’
```

I learnt from Stackoverflow that the above method is initializer list which is supported from C++11 onwards. Can you tell me how to initialize mymap? Oneway I am thinking is to insert pairs one by one in to mymap.

Answer (score 0):

in C++98 you can't initialize something like a map when you declare it. You can only insert each pair as a separate statement:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, int> mymap;
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(key1,1));
```

Comment: I thought of this. Looking for other methods if there are any.

Comment: There aren't any. If you want the map to be constant and have to use C++98, you can have a map creation function that returns the map you want.